# Web login to college wifi network is not working anymore

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

The title for this one might be misleading, I know that there are a number of questions related to wifi and connectivity issues, but, i'm quite sure that this is a separate issue.

In my college's Wi-Fi system, we have a portal, one logs into the said portal and upon verification of your credentials, you can access the net. Now, recently these guys decided to integrate a number of networks into one large, all-encompassing network, and since then accessing the net via Ubuntu has become an extremely tedious task. Here's the weird part, at the same time if i boot into Win7, it works just fine, no issues whatsoever. I spoke to some other people too, and all those with Ubuntu are facing this issue.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can suggest some fix to this issue because it's rather stupid to log into Windows just to access the net, seeing how all my work and basically everything is on my Ubuntu system.

My system is running on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to type the password in yourself?

If so, please don't forget that ubuntu keyboard works a little differently than a Windows keyboard does - namely, caps lock won't include punctuation or numbers.

Might be irrelevant, depends on the password, but it did cause me some trouble yesterday when I installed ubuntu 12.04 and tried to log in.

Comment: yep, i need to type the password myself, however, that's not the issue really, it was working fine for the greater portion of the year, got messed up recently. Thank you for answering, though.